# Stolen Macbook Has a New Name

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

My macbook was stolen a few weeks ago. When I go to icloud it now has a new name for the device. It alerted me that a sound was played, but there's no address.

Any ideas on what happened? Why did the cloud register the changed name without getting me a location?

Thanks!

Comment: because macbooks don't have GPS? it relies on other methods to obtain a location and they aren't always available or reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The Find My Mac does not provide a location when used with Ethernet. I tried using Ethernet, it said that my current location is not available, but when I used Wi-Fi, it has a location. So, the MacBook is connected to Ethernet, I guess.